# Web-SQL query triggers both success and failure callbacks

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I am using web data base in google chrome and the executeSql function trigger both succes and failure signal !

```
function succes(){
    alert("succes");
}

function failure(){
    alert("failure");
}

var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
              "goal(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, goals TEXT, added_on DATETIME, appartient INTEGER, ok INTEGER)", []);
 });

 $('#button').click(function(){
    db.transaction(function(tx){
    var goalText = $('#entry').val();
    var addedOn = new Date();
    var appartient = 0;
    var ok = 0;
    alert(goalText);
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO goal(goals, added_on, appartient, ok) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",
    [goalText, addedOn, appartient, ok],
    succes(),
    failure());
 });

});
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: You probably want to rename your function to `success`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **calling** `succes` and `failure` and passing their (`undefined`) **return values** to `executeSql`.

Take away the `()` and pass the functions instead.